# Hazelcast cache not evicted based on <time-to-live-seconds>

Tags: spring, caching, hazelcast, spring-cache, hazelcast-imap

We configured the `<time-to-live-seconds>` as 1200(20 mins) but the cache is getting evicted automatically after a minute from the cache creation time.

Can someone please tell how to make the cache live for specified time period?

Answer (score 9):

Below snippet in `hazelcast.xml` sets the `time-to-live-seconds` attribute for entries in "simpleMap" as 150 seconds. Entries that are older than 150 secs and not updated for 150 secs will get automatically evicted from the map.

```
<map name="simpleMap">
    <backup-count>0</backup-count>
    <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
    <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
    <time-to-live-seconds>30</time-to-live-seconds>
    <max-size>3000</max-size>
    <eviction-percentage>30</eviction-percentage>
    <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PutIfAbsentMapMergePolicy</merge-policy>
</map>
```

I have attached an entry listener (if using ver3.5, please use `MapListener` interface)  to "simpleMap" for testing purposes, which prints the key and value whenever an entry is evicted from the map.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    HazelcastInstance instance = HazelcastHelper.getHazelcastInstance();
    IMap<String, String> map = instance.getMap("simpleMap");
    map.addEntryListener(new SimpleMapEntryListener(), true);

    map.put("evictme", "value");
    printTime();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000 * 60);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    printTime();
}

private static void printTime()
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println( sdf.format(cal.getTime()) );
}

class SimpleMapEntryListener implements EntryListener<String, String>
{

    @Override
    public void entryEvicted(EntryEvent<String, String> arg0) 
    {
        System.out.println("Key : " + arg0.getKey() + " Value: " + arg0.getOldValue() + " evicted.");
        // print current time here.
    }
    // Add other overriden methods.

}
```

If you execute the code given above, you can see that entry <"evictme", "value"> gets evicted automatically only after 30 seconds.

You might need to check your `max-idle-seconds` configuration too (See that in the above example, it is set to zero which means infinite). Cache will get evicted according to `max-idle-seconds`, if it is set ( i.e. not zero).

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer. Seems like EntryListener now has been deprecated and replaced by MapListener instead: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Distributed_Events/Event_Listener_for_Members/Listening_for_Map_Events.html